# Update ListView After Assigning ItemSource to ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am very confuse in this topic.I am just taking One Single ListView.

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image Source="Assets/button_register.png"  Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,15,8,8" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sender}" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>

                    <Image Source="Assets/button_register.png"  Grid.Row="1" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Receiver}"  FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Image Source="Assets/scroll_line_addcategory.png" Grid.Row="2" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="4,8,4,0" />
                </Grid>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And this list view bind with following class

```
 public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Sender = string.Empty;
    public string Receiver = string.Empty;
    public string SenderVisibility = string.Empty;
    public string ReceiverVisibility = string.Empty;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string send
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Sender;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.Sender)
            {
                this.Sender = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("send");
            }
        }
    }
    public string receive
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Receiver;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.Receiver)
            {
                this.Receiver = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("receive");
            }
        }
    }
    public string receivevisible
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ReceiverVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.ReceiverVisibility)
            {
                this.ReceiverVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("receivevisible");
            }
        }
    }
    public string sendervisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.SenderVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.SenderVisibility)
            {
                this.SenderVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("sendervisibility");
            }
        }
    }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

While Application load at that time i'm simply load Static data at 6 time.

```
  private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //List<User> ls = new List<User>();
        for (int a = 0; a <= 5; a++)
        {
            User u = new User();
            u.Sender = "Hello";
            u.Receiver = "World";
            ls.Add(u);
        }
        lst1.ItemsSource = ls;
        Debug.WriteLine("Ls Count :: " + ls.Count);


    }
```

but problem is occur while again i am Adding Data in this same list View After assigning source but Listview is not Update.

```
   private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     User n=new User(){
         Sender="Chirag",
         Receiver="Solanki"
     };
     ls.Add(n);
     lst1.ItemsSource = ls;
    }
```

So, Plz Help me if any one have any superb idea.

Comment: you have not posted the complete XAML code.  could you include it please? specifically the beginnings of the `<listview>`

Comment: You should bind to properties not variables - change in xaml: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Sender}"` to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding send}" ` - in your version you are also running `NotifyPropertyChanged("send");` which won't invoke *Sender*. Also think of using *ObservableCollection* instead of setting *ItemsSource* multiple times.

Comment: Thanks All And its simply Understandable I starting listview. i know its missing but it's my problem so Sorry for that...@Mike Duncan

Comment: Thanx Romanza, I am Beginner in this so it's might be having some Error in Code.Did yo have any Example of ObservableCollection. How to use This.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to set `ItemsSource` once. Setting it again won't change anything. Instead of `List<User>` you should use `ObservableCollection<User>`. It will handle changes in the list automatically.

Moreover, you have many errors in `User` class. Here's fixed code:

```
class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string sender = string.Empty;
    private string receiver = string.Empty;
    private string senderVisibility = string.Empty;
    private string receiverVisibility = string.Empty;

    public string Sender
    {
        get
        {
            return sender;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.sender)
            {
                this.sender = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Sender");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Receiver
    {
        get
        {
            return this.receiver;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.receiver)
            {
                this.receiver = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Receiver");
            }
        }
    }
    public string ReceiverVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.receiverVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.receiverVisibility)
            {
                this.receiverVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ReceiverVisibility");
            }
        }
    }
    public string SenderVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.senderVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.senderVisibility)
            {
                this.senderVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SenderVisibility");
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

When you call `NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName)` the value of `propertyName` must match the name of the property. You messed up properties and fields. These private lowercase ones are fileds. Public camel case values are properties. In XAML you have to bind properties not fields.

Comment: Ya,It's Superb One.It's Working Proper.but here i have one Problem.While i Click on Add Button list View is not update.newly Added item is not Display.

Comment: Do you use ObservableCollection?

Comment: No I am not use This.

Comment: Just replace `List<User>` with `ObservableCollection<User>` That's all you have to do :)

Comment: Thanx bro.You Are Superb It's Working Perfect.Thank you very much.